# Enabling pg_cron extension on postgres database without rds_superuser

Tags: postgresql, cron, amazon-rds, psql, pg-cron

I'm trying to follow this article to enable the pg_cron extension on my postgres RDS instance on AWS:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL_pg_cron.html

it says to run on the **rds_superuser**

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_cron;
```

However, I'm logged in under a different user, I don't currently have access to the **rds_superuser** account. The message I get is:

```
SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied to create extension "pg_cron"
  Hint: Must be superuser to create this extension.
```

Can anyone please tell me a work-around for this without having to contact a DBA? Can I grant superuser or create a new user with superuser to get around this?

it looks like the current user I have access to only shows on the pg_tables access to:

```
rolinherit - X
rolcanlogin - X
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out that if you go to your RDS database instance on AWS, you can "Modify" the RDS instance, and change the **master** password for the `sysadmin` user. I was then able sign in with this user and do what I needed to do.